# Estimating the integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to find an estimate for the modulus of the integral given below.
|$\int_0^r\frac{w^{z-1}}{w^2+1}dw$|, where $r\in[0,1]$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $Re(z)>0$.
Any hint will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write
$1/(w^2+1)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n w^{2n}
$,
multiply, and integrate term by term.
The result will be a series with alternating lower and upper bounds.

(added later)

Since
$\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k
$,
putting $-x$ for $x$ gives
$\dfrac{1-(-1)^nx^n}{1+x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kx^k
$,
so
$\dfrac{1-(-1)^nx^{2n}}{1+x^2}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kx^{2k}
$
so
$\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}
=\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{1+x^2}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kx^{2k}
$.

Now we can integrate.

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^r\dfrac{w^{z-1}}{w^2+1}dw
&=\int_0^rw^{z-1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^kw^{2k}+\dfrac{(-1)^nw^{2n}}{1+w^2}\right)dw\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\int_0^rw^{z-1}w^{2k}dw+\int_0^rw^{z-1}\dfrac{(-1)^nw^{2n}}{1+w^2}dw\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\int_0^rw^{2k+z-1}dw+\int_0^r\dfrac{(-1)^nw^{2n+z-1}}{1+w^2}dw\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\dfrac{w^{2k+z}}{2k+z}|_0^r+(-1)^nE_{2n+z-1}(r)
\qquad E_{v}(r)=\int_0^r\dfrac{w^{v}}{1+w^2}dw\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k\dfrac{r^{2k+z}}{2k+z}+(-1)^nE_{2n+z-1}(r)\\
\end{array}
$

Here are some easy bounds for
$E_v(r)$.

$\begin{array}\\
E_{v}(r)
&=\int_0^r\dfrac{w^{v}}{1+w^2}dw\\
&<\int_0^rw^{v}\\
&=\dfrac{r^{v+1}}{v+1}\\
E_{v}(r)
&=\int_0^r\dfrac{w^{v}}{1+w^2}dw\\
&>\int_0^r\dfrac{w^{v}}{1+r^2}dw\\
&=\dfrac{r^{v+1}}{(v+1)(1+r^2)}\\
\end{array}
$